# How to display multiple TextView without changing their positions?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have some TextView(s) with fixed positions. Top left, Top right, Bottom left, Bottom right of the screen. The program worked if one TextView is viewed individually.

I tried RelativeLayout and LinearLayout to collect them all, and used setContentView. But none of these actually worked, and I don't want them to re-arrange the text position unnecessarily.

How to make the code work? For example, this code just makes all the text placed on top of each other.

```
    RelativeLayout views = new RelativeLayout(this);

    views.addView(tv_1);
    views.addView(tv_2);
    views.addView(tv_3);
    views.addView(tv_4);

    setContentView(views);
```

Note : I used Gravity to align my text (that is why they have fixed positions and I want to display all of them without changing where they originally are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to initialize layout for each TextView. Not sure what it is for, but it works.

```
tv_1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
tv_2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
tv_3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
tv_4.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```